# How to make it so the user can replace a sentence they typed can be replaced in Java

Tags: java

So I am trying to make the program ask the user the following and get the following answer:

For example:
Type a 2nd Sentence Below:
This is a book (user inputs this)
Choose what string of characters do you want to replace:
book (user inputs this)
Choose what new string will be used in the replacement:
car (user inputs this)
The text after the replacement is:  This is a car.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringManipulation {

public static void main(String[]args) {

    /*This is where the user can type a second sentence*/
    System.out.println("Type a 2nd Sentence Below:");
    Scanner sd = new Scanner(System.in);
    String typingtwo = sd.nextLine();

    String sending;
    /*Here the program will tell the user a message*/
    System.out.println("This is your sentence in capital letters:");
    sending = typingtwo.toUpperCase();
    System.out.println(sending);
    /*Here the program will tell the user another message*/
    System.out.println("This is your sentence in lower letters:");
    sending = typingtwo.toLowerCase();
    System.out.println(sending);

    System.out.print("Your Token Count:");
    int FrequencyTwo = new StringTokenizer(sending, " ").countTokens();
    System.out.println(FrequencyTwo);

    String charactertwo = new String(typingtwo);
    System.out.print("Your Character Length:");
    System.out.println(charactertwo.length());

    String repWords;
    String newWord;
    String nwords;
    String twords;
    System.out.println("Choose what string of characters do you want to    
replace");
    repWords = sd.next();
    System.out.println("Choose what new string will be used in the replacement");
    nwords = sc.next();
    twords = typingtwo.replace(repWords,nwords);
    System.out.printf("The text after the replacement is: %s \n",nwords);

}
  }
```

I have tried everything but for some reason I keep getting the word that they chose at the end only. Pleas help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using [Scanner.nextLine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) instead of [Scanner.next](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next())

refer to the Java API documentation to understand the difference between the two

Here is another problem:

```
twords = typingtwo.replace(repWords,nwords);
System.out.printf("The text after the replacement is: %s \n",nwords);
```

You are printing `nwords` instead of `twords`.

Comment: I tried that and it still only gave me the word I wanted to replace, not the whole sentence.

Comment: @wxAnalysis I spotted another error. check my update

Comment: @wxAnalysis [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) is what to do when someone answers your question. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark ✔ beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. There is no need to add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you".

Answer (score 0):

Two errors i could see.

1. nwords = sc.next(); here it should give compilation error as scanner instance name is sd.
2. You are trying to print nwords at the end. it should be "twords".